# Fetch the value from jquery's autofill dropdown not showing

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, onchange

I want to fetch the value from jQuery's autofill dropdown which comes from mysql for the max input attribute and I have tried this code

```
$a = mysqli_query($connect,"SELECT ID_PENUNJANG, BIAYA, STOK FROM penunjang_pesta ");
$array = array();
foreach ($a as $item) {
    $array[$item['ID_PENUNJANG']] = $item;
}
$json = 'var itema = ' . json_encode($array) . ';';
```

and this my script

```
<script>
<?php echo $json;?>

$("#PENUNJANG").change(function(){
    var sid = $(this).val();
    $("input[name='BIAYA']").val(itema[sid].BIAYA);
    $("input[name='STOK']").val(itema[sid].STOK);
    // $("input[name='JUMLAH']").val(itema[sid].STOK).max; i'm try this too
    $("input[name='JUMLAH']").attr({
        "max": val(itema[sid].STOK),
        "min": 1
    });
});
</script>
```

but my max value is not showing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change `val(itema[sid].STOK)` to `itema[sid].STOK` 
the full code will be like this:

```
<script>
<?php echo $json;?>

$("#PENUNJANG").change(function(){
    var sid = $(this).val();
    $("input[name='BIAYA']").val(itema[sid].BIAYA);
    $("input[name='STOK']").val(itema[sid].STOK);
    // $("input[name='JUMLAH']").val(itema[sid].STOK).max; i'm try this too
    $("input[name='JUMLAH']").attr({
        "max": itema[sid].STOK,
        "min": 1
    });
});
</script>
```